# What steps are involved in moving mvc 3 application and associated database to new servers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, deployment

we have an MVC 3 application and its associated database deployed on rented servers.
I now want to host both on our own in house servers.
Could anyone point me in the direction of a detailed link on the this or know the steps involved.
This is gonna be completely new to me as I came in on this project after it was originally deployed.

I'm assuming we need to set up two servers with a spec identical to those currently in user and change the connection strings where required ..... but unfortunately, I'm sure there's a lot more to it ??
Thanks.

Comment: Are you going to replicate the exact same DB of the rented servers in your own servers?

Comment: yup, thats the plan.I'm hoping to keep naming as close as possible to the origin, so when I do switch the like's of the connection strings aren't a mess. Basically I'm thinking a copy of the most up-to-date database, change all paths,etc in the Web.Config to that of the new servers and create a Site via IIS on the new server and deploy application to it ..... is there any major issue I should watch for ?

Comment: As far as I know I think that will be it. You could create a backup file for the actual DB and deploy it in your new server. Create the new IIS directory site and that's it.

Comment: ok then, watch this space, thanks.